# Retain state data on re render in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I cannot share the whole code as it is very complex.

The app is basically a todo list task in which we can add main task and subtasks corresponding to main tasks

Structure is like this

```
Main task 1  
1.
2.
3.
```

Now i maintain an index variable in my json structure and when send my data to the child component as

this.state.Todo[index].items

Now the problem i am facing is

- when i add the first task ie **this.state.Todo[0].items** and its subtasks then it works fine
- But if i add second task **this.state.Todo[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAhhi.jpg).items** then child componen only gets data for second index and subtasks of first child that i previously added disappears from the page.

  ```
  Main task 1
  ```

  //Disappears
- Main task 2
- 1.
- 2.
- 3.

I am not able to figure it out how to solve this issue

**UPDATE:**

here is my json

```
{
Todo:[
{name:"primary",
items:[
{
item:'',
isDone:false,
cost:0}
            ]
}
],
filter:[
{
keyword:'',
Status:"SHOW_ALL"
}
],
selectedCatelog:"0"};


**starting Component todoAdd.js**

var React=require('react');
var ReactDOM=require('react-dom');
import TodoBanner from './TodoComponents/TodoBanner.js';
import TodoForm from './TodoComponents/TodoForm.js';
import TodoList from './TodoComponents/TodoList.js';
import TodoCost from './TodoComponents/TodoCost.js';


            var TodoApp = React.createClass({
            getInitialState : function(){
                return {Todo:[{name:"primary",items:[{item:'',isDone:false,cost:0}
                ]}],filter:[{keyword:'',Status:"SHOW_ALL"}],selectedCatelog:"0"};
            },
            updateItems: function(newItem){

                var item = {item:newItem.item,isDone:false,cost:newItem.cost};

                var newtodo = this.state.Todo;
                var allItems = this.state.Todo[this.state.selectedCatelog].items.concat([item]);
                newtodo[this.state.selectedCatelog].items = allItems;
                this.setState({
                    Todo: newtodo
                });

            },
            deleteItem : function(index){

                var newtodo = this.state.Todo;
                var allItems = this.state.Todo[this.state.selectedCatelog].items.slice(); //copy array
                allItems.splice(index, 1); //remove element
                newtodo[this.state.selectedCatelog].items = allItems;
                this.setState({
                    Todo: newtodo
                });
            },
            filterItem : function(e){

                this.state.filter[0].Status = e.target.value;
                this.setState({
                    filter: this.state.filter
                });
            },
            searchItem : function(e){

                this.state.filter[0].keyword = e.target.value;
                this.setState({
                    filter: this.state.filter
                });
            },
            AddCatalog: function(newCatalog){
                var Catalog = {name:newCatalog,items:[]};
                var newtodo = this.state.Todo.concat([Catalog]);
                this.setState({
                    Todo: newtodo
                });
            },
            setID:function(index)
            {

            if(index-this.state.selectedCatelog===1)
            {
                this.setState({
                    selectedCatelog: index
                });

            }

            },
            setSelectedCatalog: function(index){


            },
            setIndexItem:function(index)
            {

                this.setState({
                    selectedCatelog: index
                });
            },
            render: function(){


            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.Todo))




                const AppBarExampleIcon = () => (
      <AppBar title="Module Cost Estimation" />
    );
                return (
                    <div>
                        <div>
                        <MuiThemeProvider>
                        <AppBarExampleIcon />
                        </MuiThemeProvider>

                        <TodoCost cost={this.state.Todo}/>
                            <ToDoCatalogForm onFormSubmit = {this.AddCatalog} />
                            <ToDoCatelog setItemId={this.setIndexItem} set={this.updateItems} onSelectDemo={this.setID} selectedID = {this.state.selectedCatelog} onSelected={this.setSelectedCatalog} Todos = {this.state.Todo} />

                        </div>
                        <div>

                            <TodoList ListIndex={this.state.selectedCatelog}  items = {this.state.Todo} filter = {this.state.filter} onDelete={this.deleteItem}/>


                            <ToDoFilter onFilter = {this.filterItem} onSearch = {this.searchItem} filter={this.state.filter}/>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
    ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

When i Add a task its name gets added in name property of Json and when i enter subtasks then subtasks are populated in items property corressponding to the name and i am updating the index using **selectedCatelog**.Whenever a new task is added **selectedCatelog** is updated in **setIndexItem** method and then i pass entire json to **TodoList** Component

Here is the screenshot **before** adding second main task

[image]

Here is the screenshot **after** adding second main task
[image]

Comment: It'd be great if you could post more code because from the provided description it's not really clear as to how you use the index variable, and how you're charging the state.

Comment: @Grandas has a point. It sounds like an issue that is coming from state manipulation, overwriting your current state with the new one. Some details on how these changes happen exactly would help a lot.

Comment: i have updated the question.Please help

Comment: Where are you updating state? Share that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

For the few information you give us it looks like the problem is updating the state.

When you update a member of the state you overwrite that member with the new one, so you have to take the information you had before and add the new one.

Besides, you can't directly mutate the state like `this.state.Todo.push(newTodo)`, so being Todo an array you should use a method like concat to add a new element as it returns a new Array.

```
const { Todo } = this.state;
let newTodo = {"name":'sec',"items":[2,4,5,7]}
this.setState({ Todo:Todo.concat([newTodo])});
```